# TypeError: fs.createReadStream is not a function [React]

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv

I am trying to read a csv file within my React app. My code is as follows:

```
const verifyUser = (e) => {
    e?.preventDefault();
    alert("Hello");
    const csv = require('csv-parser');
    const fs = require('fs');
    fs.createReadStream('/passcode.csv')
        .pipe(csv())
        .on('passcode', (row) => {
            console.log(row);
        })
        .on('end', () => {
            console.log('CSV file successfully processed');
    });
};
```

When I execute the code I am getting the following error:

> TypeError: fs.createReadStream is not a function

What am I doing wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: The filesystem does not 'exist' in a browser.

Comment: 'fs' is a core module of NodeJS, which is available only on the server-side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filesystem does not 'exist' in a browser. You don't have access. If you're trying to read a .csv file from a webserver, use a client like `fetch()`. If you want to let a user pick a file from their computer, use `<input type="file" />`